copy/paste behaviour changed since upgrade
I just upgraded to Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS and clipboard behaviour has changed.
Now, when I copy from my browser (Chrome Version 131.0.6778.108) by selecting text and hitting Ctrl-Insert, I cannot paste into my terminal with Shift-Insert. To paste into my terminal (Gnome Terminal 3.52.0), I have to right click and choose Paste.
I don't want to use my mouse to paste - how do I fix this?

You should be able to paste using CTRL+SHIFT+V

Thanks @user535733. Is there a standard way to customise shortcut keys and clipboards?

Note that as soon as you have selected any text in any program on a Linux system, you can now paste that text using the mouse's middle button. This is (IMO) far more practical and intuitive and easy to use than needing to hit multi-key combinations as well as using the mouse to select. Just select, and then middle click paste and you're done.
